# Unity3d error CS0119

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a game in Unity3D and I am getting an error on this line:

```
Cube[i] = new Cube(S.ObjProp,S.TypeProp,S.MoveProp,S.AllergieProp,S.VisabilityProp,S.MainMaterial,S.SecondaryMaterial);
```

I googled the error and found that it occurs when you dont use the new word infront of your constructor. I am using the new word tho so I dont understand, this is the error:

```
Assets/Resources/Scripts/Classes.cs(66,41): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected
```

This is the class where my constuctor is in:

```
    public class Cube{

                public Transform CubeObj{get; set;}
                public string CubeType{get; set;}
                public Vector3[] CubeMovement{get; set;}
                public string[] CubeAllergies{get; set;}
                public bool CubeVisability{get; set;}
                public Material CubeMainMat{get; set;}
                public Material CubeSecondaryMat{get; set;}

                public Cube(Transform _cubeObj, string _cubeType, Vector3[] _cubeMovement, string[] _allergies, bool _visability, Material _mainMat, Material _secondMat)
                {
                    CubeObj = _cubeObj;
                    CubeType = _cubeType;
                    CubeMovement = _cubeMovement;
                    CubeAllergies = _allergies;
                    CubeVisability = _visability;
                    CubeMainMat = _mainMat;
                    CubeSecondaryMat = _secondMat;
                }
            }
```

And this is this is the class where I get the error:

```
public static Cube[] LoadLevel (int _currentLevel)
        {
            // Bouw errors in als er geen levels in de map staan of de naam niet kopt met de levels.
            string levelName = "Level" + _currentLevel;
            GameObject levelObj = Resources.Load("Prefabs/Levels/" + levelName) as GameObject;
            throwLevelLoadError(levelObj);
            Cube[] cubes = new Cube[levelObj.transform.childCount];
            throwMissingCubesError(levelObj.transform.childCount);

            GameObject rotateXObj = new GameObject("RotateXObj");
            GameObject rotateYObj = new GameObject("RotateYObj");
            rotateYObj.transform.SetParent(rotateXObj.transform);

                for(int i = 0; i < cubes.Length; i++)
                {
                    GameObject curCube = MonoBehaviour.Instantiate(levelObj.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject) as GameObject;
                    curCube.transform.SetParent(rotateYObj.transform);
                    CubePropertiesS S = curCube.GetComponent<CubePropertiesS>();
                    Cube[i] = new Cube(S.ObjProp,S.TypeProp,S.MoveProp,S.AllergieProp,S.VisabilityProp,S.MainMaterial,S.SecondaryMaterial);
                }

        return cubes;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cube` is a type, `cubes` is the *name* of the array

im sure you meant: `cubes[i] = new Cube(S.ObjProp,S.TypeProp,S.MoveProp,S.AllergieProp,S.VisabilityProp,S.MainMaterial,S.SecondaryMaterial);`